# Transliteration of Unicode in Java without using of Google Api?

Tags: java, unicode, unicode-string, transliteration

Is there any solution from English unicode to Gujarati unicode?
Suppose unicode for a = \u0061 then it will translate અ = u0095

Comment: Transliteration means replacing letters by some letters of another alphabet, so in the programming sense, it’s very simple string manipulation (read a string character by character, output characters in a table-driven manner). Depending on the transliteration scheme, there can be complications. But which scheme would you apply, and what do you see as problematic then?

Comment: The character code U+0095 is wrong. Apparently the one you want is U+0A85. How other characters shoulc be translitterated is not obvious; could you link to a spec, an implementation, or some additional examples? http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a85/index.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Unicode CLDR provides files containing instructions on how to transliterate from Latin to Gujarati. The instructions for transformation are in .XML files using [Locale Data Markup Language](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/#Transform_Rules).

[Latin-Gujarati](http://www.unicode.org/repos/cldr/trunk/common/transforms/Latin-Gujarati.xml) involves:

1. Filtering the string to characters or character ranges described by

   `['.0-9A-Za-z~À-ÅÇ-ÏÑ-ÖÙ-Ýà-åç-ïñ-öù-ýÿ-ďĒ-ĥĨ-İĴ-ķĹ-ľŃ-ňŌ-őŔ-ťŨ-žƠ-ơƯ-ưǍ-ǜǞ-ǣǦ-ǭǰǴ-ǵǸ-țȞ-ȟȦ-ȳʔ́̃-̄̆-̇̐̔-̣̥̱́̈́̕΅-ΆΈ-ΊΌΎ-ΐά-ΰό-ώϓЃЌЎЙйѓќўӁ-ӂӐ-ӑӖ-ӗӢ-ӣӮ-ӯḀ-ẙẠ-ỹἁἃ-ἅἇἉἋ-ἍἏἑἓ-ἕἙἛ-Ἕἡἣ-ἥἧἩἫ-ἭἯἱἳ-ἵἷἹἻ-ἽἿὁὃ-ὅὉὋ-Ὅὑὓ-ὕὗὙὛὝὟὡὣ-ὥὧὩὫ-ὭὯάέήίόύώᾁᾃ-ᾅᾇᾉᾋ-ᾍᾏᾑᾓ-ᾕᾗᾙᾛ-ᾝᾟᾡᾣ-ᾥᾧᾩᾫ-ᾭᾯ-ᾱᾴᾸ-ᾹΆῄΈΉ῎ῐ-ῑΐῘ-ῙΊ῞ῠ-ῡΰῥῨ-ῩΎ-Ῥ΅ῴΌΏK-Å\uE04D\uE064]`
2. Putting the result of the previous step in [Normal Form D](http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/)
3. Lowercasing the result of the previous step
4. Performing [Latin-InterIndic](http://www.unicode.org/repos/cldr/trunk/common/transforms/Latin-InterIndic.xml) transform on the result of the previous step. As you can see from the file, this has already gotten pretty compilcated and I am not going into the details of this step.
5. Performing [InterIndic-Gujarati](http://www.unicode.org/repos/cldr/trunk/common/transforms/InterIndic-Gujarati.xml) on the result of previous step. Same note as previous step.
6. Putting the result of the previous step in [Normal Form C](http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/)

So if we do this for the letter `"a"`, and skip right to step 4, which describes the following relevant transforms:

```
$wa=\uE005
a→$wa
```

We have `"\uE005"` now. Now step 5:

```
\uE005→અ
```

So we end up with `અ`, and it is unchanged by step 6.

---

You probably want to look at [CLDR Eclipse Setup](http://cldr.unicode.org/development/eclipse-setup) but I'm not sure if these are just development tools for the cldr maintainers and I actually have no idea if anyone has implemented a library for this in java.